# Como realizar una herencia multiple en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, poo

Hola amigos de stackOverFlow, tengo una duda soy nuevo en JS en todo para ser sincero, tengo una duda con la programacion OOP para ser mas exacto con la herencia multiple
estoy realizando ejercicios con clases pero al momento de querer heredar mas de una clase
no puedo hacerlo >:v
Pense que era como en PHP pero no es asi a continuacion muestro el codigo.

```
i class Mueble {

   constructor(tipoDeMueble){
     this.tipoDeMueble = tipoDeMueble;
    }

  }

 class Mesa extends Mueble {
   constructor(figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,descripcionMesa){
     super(tipoDeMueble);

     this.figura= figura;
     this.tipoDeMesa= tipoDeMesa;
     this.dimensiones= dimensiones;
     this.color= color;
     this.tipoDeMaterial=  tipoDeMaterial
     this.descripcionMesa= descripcionMesa
    }

  }

  //funcion multi(Mesa, Mueble) no funciona
                  //Estilo php
  class Producto extends Mesa, Mueble {
   constructor(tipoDeMueble,figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,    
               descripcionMesa, precio){   

 super(tipoDeMueble,figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,descripcionMesa)
    this.precio= precio;
    }

get descripcionProducto() {
     datos= ` ${tipoDeMueble} ${figura} ${tipoDeMesa} ${this.dimensiones}   
              ${this.color} ${this.tipoDeMaterial} ${this.descripcionMesa}   
              ${this.precio} `;
     return datos; 
    }
  }

  let producto= new Producto('Mesa','cuadrada','Vintage','24x30','roja','Cedro','Mesa 
  mamalona',3300);

 document.write(descripcionProducto)
```

En la consola me aparece un error
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing { before class body
Estoy tratatando de realizar de otras formas pero no me instancia el objeto.

Comment: **Javascript no soporta la herencia múltiple**, [lee aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#no_multiple_inheritance) para más detalles.

Comment: rayos! >;v. Gracias amigo

Comment: [Versión en castellano](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#sin_herencia_m%C3%BAltiple) para mejor comprensión. Ahí te muestran una forma de crear herencia múltiple *ilusoria*. Pero, reconsidera tu modelo de datos y entérate con claridad de lo que es la herencia. ¿Por qué crees que `Mesa` debe heredar de `Producto`? La herencia no es para hacerte la *ilusión* de resolver problemas de lógica o para hacerte la *ilusión* de acortar código. La herencia es algo serio, que deberías considerar incluso de forma metafísica.

Comment: Lol ya vi que eras el que me ayudo con el consejo de la otra vez gracias amigo se me hacia parecido tu nick. Lo leere te agradezco.

Comment: Sobre tu pregunta yo considero que mesa hereda de producto porque producto es objeto final de un mueble basado en una mesa que da como resultado en un producto segun yo jaja, si tienes libros de metafisica o logica que recomiendes los leere. Gracias

Comment: Por lo general la *herencia* tiene que ver con el ser de las cosas. Ejemplos: `Empleado, Estudiante, Profesor` podrían heredar todas de `Persona`, porque comparten entre sí el *ser* persona y atributos como `nombre, sexo, fecha nacimiento`... `Vaca, Tigre, Perro`  podrían heredar de `Animal` por lo mismo. Un `Producto` es algo demasiado genérico como para querer hacerlo *padre* de otras entidades que nada tienen que ver con él metafísicamente. En tu diseño, millones de cosas podrian ser `Producto` pero no desde el punto de vista de la herencia, sino desde un punto de vista contextual.

Comment: joder que pro! :v Gracias amigo tengo mucho que aprender sin duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto mi problema gracias A.Cedano por pasar la documentacion, la verdad que esto de la programación basada en prototipos es algo nuevo para mi ya que aprendí a programar en PHP

A continuación muestro mi forma de solucionar mi problema instanciando propiedades de mas de una clase.

```
i class Mueble {

   constructor(tipoDeMueble){
     this.tipoDeMueble = tipoDeMueble;
   }

 }

class Mesa extends Mueble {

constructor(tipoDeMueble,  
 figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,descripcionMesa){
    super(tipoDeMueble, 
 figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,descripcionMesa)
    
 this.figura= figura;
 this.tipoDeMesa= tipoDeMesa;
 this.dimensiones= dimensiones;
 this.color= color;
 this.tipoDeMaterial=  tipoDeMaterial
 this.descripcionMesa= descripcionMesa
 }

}

class TipoDeMesa extends Mesa {

  constructor(tipoDeMueble,figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial, descripcionMesa, precio){ 

 super(tipoDeMueble,figura,tipoDeMesa,dimensiones,color,tipoDeMaterial,descripcionMesa,precio)
        this.precio= precio;
    }

}

    /*
     Con esta funcion constructora hago la herencia 
     de clases
    */

    TipoDeMesa.prototype.getInfo= function(d) {
     d= ` ${this.tipoDeMueble} ${this.figura} ${this.tipoDeMesa}   
     ${this.dimensiones} ${this.color} ${this.tipoDeMaterial}  
     ${this.descripcionMesa} ${this.precio} `;
     document.write(d); 
    }


    let tipo_mesa= new 
     TipoDeMesa('Mesa','cuadrada','Vintage','24x30','roja','Cedro','Mesa  
      mamalona',3300);

    tipo_mesa.getInfo()
```

De esta forma pude hacerlo, entiendo que pudiera hacerse mas compleja o de diferente forma pero de momento no tengo mucho conocimiento en JS para poder hacerlo pero me sirvió. Si ven que no esta bien escrito el código de ejemplo no es flojera o que no haya dado cuenta si no que no me permite dar espacios
cuando quiero dar espacio no me dejo en esas líneas :,v . También cambie el nombre de la clase producto por recomendaciones de A.Cedano buscare mas información sobre lógica y metafísica.